# Delete all db schema in test teardown using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nunit, schema

I am looking for the best way to delete all schema changes(all tables really) made when unit testing.

I am using fluent to map my entities and create the schema in the Setup of my tests. I want to be able to delete the schema changes at the end of the tests in the Teardown.

I am using nhibernates SchemaExport to generate the schema.

Sure this is being done at the moment and would appreciate some pointers.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SchemaExport.Execute has parameter to justDrop.